# Pass multiple optional parameters in Laravel 9

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-9

I am trying to create a route that takes either one of two parameters. However the dd returns me `$b_id, null` instead of `null, $b_id`. How can I pass only b as a parameter and omit a?

**web.php**

```
Route::get('myroute/{a?}/{b?}', [MyController::class, 'testFunction'])
    ->name('test.testFunction');
```

**Controller**

```
public function testFunction( $a = null,  $b = null) 
{
    dd($a, $b);
    // stuff
}
```

**Ajax call**

```
function test($b_id) {
    $url = "{{ route('test.testFunction', ':b') }}";
    $url = $url.replace(":b", $b_id);
    $.ajax({
        url: $url,
        type: 'GET'
    })}
```

Comment: There's no practical way to differentiate between `myroute/thisisB` vs `myroute/thisisA` you need an alternative approach. Perhaps you are asking your route to do too much

Comment: I've found a workaround by having $url = "{{ route('test.testFunction', ['a'=>'null', 'b'=>':b']) }}"; But it makes the use of optionnal parameters pointless

Comment: Yeah, chaining optional parameters like that has never been supported in Laravel; unless you literally put `/null/1` in the URL (or `/0/1`, `/blank/1`, etc), Laravel has no way of knowing that you intend `1` to be `{b?}` instead of `{a?}`. Depending on what `a` and `b` are supposed to be, you might just be better of using Query String parameters, i.e. `?a=&b=1` (`$request->input('a')` would be `null`, and `$request->input('b')` would be `1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really possible at the moment but there is a workaround.
You can pass the parameters in an named array and change the route to simply `Route::get('myroute' ...)`:

```
route('test.testFunction', ['a' => 'xyz', 'b' => 'yzt'])
===== creates
http://myroute?a=xyz&b=yzt
```

Afterwards you can check if the parameters `a` or `b` are present and retrieve them normally if they are.

Comment: This is pretty much the same as sending 'a' and 'b' in data and having testFunction(Request $request). Thanks for your answer, shame it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Yes exactly, just with a GET request instead of a POST request :)